# replace "" for ' when is not a anchor tag in php

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

Hi i want to replace all " citations for citation simple ' but not when is a anchor

for example this

```
Lorem "ipsum" dolor sit amet, <a href="#">sit amet</a>
```

to this

```
Lorem 'ipsum' dolor sit amet, <a href="#">sit amet</a>
```

im doing this `$valFieldBody = str_replace('"', "''", $valFieldBody);`

but that replace all " i dont know if i can use `str_replace` or `preg_replace` funcion with negative condition like `!=` or `<>`

could you please help me

thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that help me (y)

Comment: @Wiktor Now that you have posted an answer, please delete your comments.

Answer (score 2):

The preg_replace function allows you to make multiple combinations to replace, in this case I look for the string that replaces only accepts spaces and alphanumeric characters that are inside ( " " )  in your case the string "ipsum", can be extended to other characters if desired

Example with your string

Update code:

```
$text='Lorem "ipsum" dolor sit amet, <a href="#">sit amet</a>';
$text = preg_replace('/\"([A-Za-z0-9? ,_-]+)\"(?=[^<>]*(?:<|$))/', "'$1'", $text);
echo $text;
//out--> Lorem 'ipsum' dolor sit amet, <a href="#">sit amet</a>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [SKIP-FAIL regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
preg_replace('~<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*F)|"~', "'", $valFieldBody);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/swny8T/2).

**Pattern details**

- `<[^>]+>` - matches `<`, 1+ chars other than `>`, and then `>`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - 2 PCRE verbs omitting the matched text and making the regex engine search for the next match after the end of the current match
- `|` - or
- `"`  - a double quote in other contexts.